# IAB-Service - dispose of in onActivityResult?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Is it "ok" to dispose of the IAB-Service connection in `onActivityResult` *if the result was `true`* for a managed product (which is the *only* product)? Some of my users are reporting a memory leak of 100MB+ due the the IAB-Service (even though I'm disposing of it correctly in `onDestroy()`).